# can't create a table with TEXT datatype SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm getting this error everytime I try to make a TEXT datatype:

```
values TEXT )"""
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "values": syntax error
```

and this is my code

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE outliers (
            DUT integer,
            time integer,
            params TEXT,
            values TEXT )"""
    )
```

can someone help me? I'm having a lot of difficulties trying to find out why

Comment: `values` is a reserved word. Use `[values]` or `"values"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` is  a reserved word in SQL (as in `insert into mytable VALUES (1, 2, 3)`). The best approach would be to choose a name that isn't a reserved word, such as `outlier_values`:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE outliers (
            DUT integer,
            time integer,
            params TEXT,
            outlier_values TEXT )"""
    )
```

If this isn't an option, you could escape the name with double quotes (`"`):

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE outliers (
            DUT integer,
            time integer,
            params TEXT,
            "values" TEXT )"""
    )
```